# Select value and flatten sublist of objects within a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, closedxml

I have a list of object where each object in the list contains a list of objects. I need to select a string from each of the objects in the sub list and include it in the main list. Basically flatten the sublist.

The goal is to input this data in a spreadsheet.

### These are my two models

```
class Phrase
{
    public string Parent { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
}
class Translation
{
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public string Translatable { get; private set; }
    public List<Phrase> Phrases { get; private set; }
}
```

### This is how a List could look like

```
{ Key = "coffee", Translatable = "", Phrase = [{ Parent = "English", Value = "Coffee" }, { Parent = "Swedish", Value = "Kaffe" }] },
{ Key = "candy", Translatable = "", Phrase = [{ Parent = "English", Value = "Candy" }, { Parent = "Swedish", Value = "Godis" }] },
{ Key = "computer", Translatable = "", Phrase = [{ Parent = "English", Value = "Computer" }, { Parent = "Swedish", Value = "Dator" }] }
```

---

As I said the goal is to insert this data into a spreadsheet, so according to the list above, the spreadsheet should in theory look like this:

```
Key      | Translatable | English  | Swedish
---------------------------------------------
coffee   |              | Coffee   | Kaffe
candy    |              | Candy    | Godis
computer |              | Computer | Dator
```

I only care about the `Value` in the Phrase object.

You can select the `Key` and `Translatable` from the List like so

```
var query = from t in parser.translations
        from p in t.Phrases
        select new { t.Key, t.Translatable };
```

which would yield

```
{ Key = "coffee", Translatable = ""},
{ Key = "candy", Translatable = ""},
{ Key = "computer", Translatable = ""}
```

But how would I then include all the values from the Phrase list to each object? The goal would be something like:

```
{ Key = "coffee", Translatable = "", Value1 = "Coffee", Value2 = "Kaffe"},
{ Key = "candy", Translatable = "", Value1 = "Candy", Value2 = "Godis"},
{ Key = "computer", Translatable = "", Value1 = "Computer", Value2 = "Dator"}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think that you're nearly there. Try this: `var query = from t in parser.translations
        from p in t.Phrases
        select new { Key = t.Key, Translatable = t.Translatable, Value1 = p.Single(phrase => phrase == "English").Value, Value2 = p.Single(phrase => phrase == "Swedish").Value };`

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. The problem is the incrementing counter in `Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3`.. of your result. There is an overload in the `select` statement of linq that has an index as parameter, but I can see no way this heps. But I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: What does `var query = from t in parser.translations
        select new { t.Key, t.Translatable, Phrases = t.Phrases.Select(z => z.Value).ToList() };` return? Could that be useful for your context?

Answer (score 0):

If you are always getting two keys in Phrase (English,Swedish) and only need values.
You can try this.

Add a new class for the result

```
class tr
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string trn { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public string Swedish { get; set; }
}
```

and use this query

```
var query = from t in translations
        select new tr() 
        { 
            Key = t.Key, 
            trn = t.Translatable, 
            English = t.Phrases.Single(p => p.Parent == "English").Value, 
            Swedish = t.Phrases.Single(p => p.Parent == "Swedish").Value 
        };
```